# Capistrano deployment with common user

Tags: deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to setup Capistrano to do our deployments, but I now stumbled upon what seems to be a common assumption of capistrano users: that the user you SSH to the remote host will have permission to write to the directory of deployment.

Here, administrators are common users with a single distinction: they can sudo. At first, I thought that would be enough, since there are some configurations related to sudo, but it seems that's not the case after all.

Is there a way around this? Creating a user shared by everyone doing deployment is not an acceptable solution.

*Edit:* to make it clear, no deploy action should happen without calling sudo -- that's the gateway point that checks whether the user is allowed to deploy or not, and it should be a mandatory checkpoint.

The presently accepted answer does not fit that criteria. It goes around sudo by granting extra permissions to the user. I'm accepting it anyway because I've come to the conclusion that Capistrano is fundamentally broken in this regard.

Comment: Have you found a way to this issue?

Comment: @pl1nk No. As I said, I think Capistrano is fundamentally broken in this regard. Presently, I do the reverse: create a user for the application, and add the public keys of everyone authorized to deploy to it's authorized_keys. Also, I've mostly ditched Capistrano for Fabric, which is way better documented, even if less powerful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume you are deploying to a Linux distro. The easiest way to resolve your issue is to create a group, say, *deployers*, and add each user who should have the permissions to deploy to that group. Once the group is created and the users are in the group, change the ownership and permissions on the deployment path.

Depending on the distro, the syntax will vary slightly. Here it is for ubuntu/debian:

Create the group:

`$ sudo groupadd deployers`

Add users to group:

`$ sudo usermod -a -G deployers daniel`

The last argument there is the username.

Next, update the ownership of the deployment path:

`$ sudo chown -R root:deployers /deploy/to/path/`

The syntax for is :. Here I am assuming that the user that currently owns the path is root. Update to which ever user should own the directory.

Finally, change the permissions on the deployment path:

`$ sudo chmod -R 0766 /deploy/to/path/`

That will allow users in the *deployers* group to read and write all files and directories beneath `/deploy/to/path`

Comment: I don't think I'm going to get anything better than this, so I'm going to accept this answer, even though it still fails my basic premise: the users are common -- they have no distinction whatsoever towards common users, except being able to sudo. Which means, as I should have stated explicitly, all deploys *must* require sudo'ing.

Comment: what do you mean by "no distinction whatsoever towards common users"?

Comment: It means that there can be no distinction between a user who can deploy and a user who cannot deploy. Sudo can tell them apart, and no one else.

Comment: how do you have sudo configured? do you have them explicitly listed in the sudoers file? also, can you show the permissions on the path you are trying to deploy to?

Comment: Yes, I have them explicitly on the sudoers file. Permissions on the path are `www-data:www-data`, `644`.

Comment: When Capistrano makes the initial deploy, the git repository is written without group permissions, which makes it impossible for others to deploy. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: As mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/a/46371/21466 you could also set the setgid bit, so that all newly created files inherit the group as well. e.g. `sudo chmod -R 2766 /deploy/to/path/`

Comment: Why to have world permissions? I think `sudo chmod -R 0760 /deploy/to/path/` would be enough.

Comment: Doing `chmod -R 6770 /var/www/userdir` worked for me. As my deploy user does not have sudo permissions.